# How does MySQL varchar know how many bytes indicate the length?

Tags: mysql, char, byte, varchar, maxlength

The MySQL manual and several StackOverflow answers make it clear that varchar uses:

- `1 byte` for varchars with `0-255 characters` in them
- `2 bytes` for varchars with `more than 255 characters` in them.

The first part makes sense. A single byte can store 256 different values, i.e. 0 through 255.

What I am trying to figure out is how MySQL knows **how many bytes indicate the length**.

Imagine a 255-char varchar starting with the following bytes: `[255][w][o][r][d]~`

According to the manual, only the first byte is used to indicate the length in this scenario. When reading the field, MySQL will somehow have to know that this is the case here, and that the second byte is not part of the length.

Now imagine a 256-char varchar starting with the following bytes: `[255][1][w][o][r][d]~`

Now MySQL miraculously knows that it should interpret the first *two bytes* as the length, when reading the field.

How does it distinguish? The only foolproof way I have come up with is to interpret only the first byte as length, then determine if the text length matches (in its current encoding), and if not, we know that the first *two* bytes must be the length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It happens at the time of definition. All length prefixes will be the same size in bytes for a particular `VARCHAR` column. The `VARCHAR` column will use 2 bytes or the `VARCHAR` column will use 1 byte, depending on the defined size in characters, and the character set.

All `VARCHAR` columns defined such that it might require more than 255 bytes use 2 bytes to store the size. MySQL isn't going to use 1 byte for some values in a column and 2 bytes for others.

MySQL documentation on [CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) states this pretty clearly (emphasis mine):

> A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255
> bytes, two length bytes if values **may** require more than 255 bytes.

If you declare a `VARCHAR(255)` column to use the `utf8` character set, it's still going to use 2 bytes for the length prefix, not 1, since the length in bytes may be greater than 255 with `utf8` characters.

Comment: Thank you. I had missed that without the emphasis.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, with UTF-8 we *always* spend 2 bytes on the length? And idem for any column that allows more than 255 characters?

Comment: With utf8, any column defined over 85 characters long is going to use a 2 byte length prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As a consideration, would it not be worthwhile (assuming ASCII for a moment) to use 1 byte wherever the *actual row's content* is up to 254, and 2 bytes wherever it is 255 or greater? The first byte's being 255 would indicate that the second byte is another length byte. Any clear reason that this approach wasn't taken?

Comment: InnoDB is big endian. If the first byte of the length prefix were always 255, you could only store values between 65280 and 65535. You can't read just one byte and know if you should keep reading unless you waste one of the bits in the first byte as a flag to indicate whether it's 1 byte or 2. If you did that, columns over 127 bytes would require 2 bytes for the length prefix.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. It would take a full bit, indeed - halving both the 255 and the 65535. Gotcha.

Comment: Probably use one bit in the column definition to indicate one byte or two versus a bit in every row.

Comment: Well, I was still talking about my (apparently not-so-feasible) idea of varying this per row, to keep smaller entries very small - i.e. save a byte on the smaller entries, while still allowing two-byte length where required.